# sql: created index does not have my flags when I check the script in the database

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In my database project I have an index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index_name] ON [schema].[tablename]
(
    [Result] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90, MAXDOP =1)
GO
```

If I run this script and after that, I go to table, right click on  the index and select "Script index as", I don't see `MAXDOP` flag and `ONLINE` flag is  set to off.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those are not features of the index, per se. They change the *operation* that *builds* the index but once the index is built, it's no different to an index that was built `offline` or with a different `maxdop` value. Or to put it shorter, they're *build* settings, not *index* settings.

And when someone makes changes to the index and thus forces a rebuild, they're free to choose whatever settings make sense at *that* time for the next build. So it's not worth storing them.

Comment: what if I have a maintenance plan that rebuilds this index daily, this means that on first index rebuild, it may affect the database performance if it's not rebuild with my flags, right?